Reading Digital PErsona HId 4500 Reader in python using C types
im new into programming, im using a sample c# code from SDK Digital persona, in python.
I read SDK and didn't found the exact conversion, im excepting the Code to read the USB finger reader and register fingerprints to match person
The codes detects the usb reader, it turns on but the code doesn't, know how to interpret and return this error:
dpfpdd_init result: 0
dpfpdd_query_devices (count) result: 96075789, device_count: 1
Press any key to continue . . .

This is the code:
import sys
import ctypes
from ctypes import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QListWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap

class FingerprintApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Fingerprint Scanner")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QLabel("Press the button to scan fingerprint", self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.device_list_label = QLabel("No devices found", self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.device_list_label)

        self.device_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.device_list)

        self.button = QPushButton("Scan Fingerprint", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.scan_fingerprint)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        self.device_handle = c_void_p()

    def scan_fingerprint(self):
        dll_path = "C:\\Program Files\\DigitalPersona\\U.are.U SDK\\Windows\\Lib\\x64\\dpfpdd.dll"

        try:
            dpfpddDll = ctypes.CDLL(dll_path)
        except OSError:
            self.label.setText(f"Library not found at {dll_path}")
            return

        if not self.init_dpfpdd(dpfpddDll):
            return

        self.query_device(dpfpddDll)

    def init_dpfpdd(self, dpfpddDll):
        dpfpdd_init = dpfpddDll.dpfpdd_init
        dpfpdd_init.argtypes = []
        dpfpdd_init.restype = c_int
        result = dpfpdd_init()
        print(f"dpfpdd_init result: {result}")

        if result != 0:
            self.label.setText("Initialization failed")
            return False
        return True

    def query_device(self, dpfpddDll):
        class DPFPDD_DEV_INFO(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ("size", c_uint),
                ("name", c_char * 32),
                ("modality", c_uint),
                ("technology", c_uint),
                ("version", c_uint),
                ("serial_num", c_char * 32),
                ("prv", c_void_p),
            ]

        dpfpdd_query_devices = dpfpddDll.dpfpdd_query_devices
        dpfpdd_query_devices.argtypes = [POINTER(c_uint), POINTER(POINTER(DPFPDD_DEV_INFO))]
        dpfpdd_query_devices.restype = c_int

        device_count = c_uint(0)
        device_info_buffer = POINTER(DPFPDD_DEV_INFO)()

        result = dpfpdd_query_devices(byref(device_count), byref(device_info_buffer))
        print(f"dpfpdd_query_devices (count) result: {result}, device_count: {device_count.value}")

        if result != 0 or device_count.value == 0:
            self.device_list_label.setText("No devices found")
            return

        self.device_list_label.setText(f"Devices found: {device_count.value}")
        for i in range(device_count.value):
            device_info = device_info_buffer[i]
            device_name = device_info.name.decode('utf-8')
            self.device_list.addItem(device_name)
            self.device_list.currentItemChanged.connect(lambda: self.open_device(dpfpddDll, device_name.encode('ascii')))

    def open_device(self, dpfpddDll, device_name):
        dpfpdd_open = dpfpddDll.dpfpdd_open
        dpfpdd_open.argtypes = [c_char_p, POINTER(c_void_p)]
        dpfpdd_open.restype = c_int

        result = dpfpdd_open(device_name, byref(self.device_handle))
        print(f"dpfpdd_open result: {result}, device_handle: {self.device_handle}")

        if result != 0:
            self.label.setText(f"Failed to open device, error code: {result}")
            return

        self.capture_fingerprint(dpfpddDll)

    def capture_fingerprint(self, dpfpddDll):
        dpfpdd_capture = dpfpddDll.dpfpdd_capture
        dpfpdd_capture.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_uint, POINTER(c_ubyte), POINTER(c_uint)]
        dpfpdd_capture.restype = c_int

        timeout = 5000  # 5 seconds

        capture_size = c_uint(512 * 512)  # Adjust the buffer size
        capture_buffer = (c_ubyte * capture_size.value)()

        print(f"Before capture: device_handle={self.device_handle}, timeout={timeout}, capture_size={capture_size.value}")
        result = dpfpdd_capture(self.device_handle, timeout, capture_buffer, byref(capture_size))
        print(f"dpfpdd_capture result: {result}, capture_size: {capture_size.value}")

        if result != 0:
            self.label.setText(f"Failed to capture fingerprint, error code: {result}")
            return

        if capture_size.value == 0:
            self.label.setText("Capture buffer is empty")
            return

        image_data = bytes(capture_buffer[:capture_size.value])
        image = QImage(image_data, 512, 512, QImage.Format_Grayscale8)  # Adjust the image dimensions as needed
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.image_label.setScaledContents(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = FingerprintApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



The code is a bit too long for a MCVE ([SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))).  also there are some cumbersome parts (passing the cdll as an argument to all methods, instead of making it an attribute, ...). What is the expected behavior? Where is the problem?

Without seeing the C prototypes of the API, we can’t tell if the ctypes declarations are correct.

Hi @CristiFati thanks for your time! I'll make it shorter next time. The goal is to query connected devices, select one, and enable scanning. The code detects a device but returns an incorrect value instead of the USB fingerprint device. Here's the output:
dpfpdd_init result: 0
dpfpdd_query_devices (count) result: 96075789, device_count: 1
Press any key to continue . . .
The C# SDK sample works, so the issue seems to be with the ctypes conversion in Python. Any guidance on handling pointers and structures would be appreciated.

Hi @MarkTolonen
Here are the C prototypes of the API functions i am using:
typedef void* DPFPDD_DEV;
int dpfpdd_init();
int dpfpdd_exit();
int dpfpdd_query_devices(unsigned int* count, DPFPDD_DEV_INFO** info);
int dpfpdd_open(const char* dev_name, DPFPDD_DEV* pdev);
int dpfpdd_capture(DPFPDD_DEV dev, unsigned int timeout, void* buffer, unsigned int* size);

[edit] the question with a simpler example and the prototypes, properly formatted as code, not as a comment.

Is results supposed to be zero for query devices? It looks like it did return one device.
